# How can i calculate Grand Total.

Tags: mysql, phpquery

I need grand total i have total Column and also some records.

For example A and B Two columns and these columns amount equal to total.

```
ColA -------20    +  ColB----------20    =      Col Total------------40
ColA -------10    +  ColB----------40    =      Col Total------------50
```

So know i need grand total. Grand total this should amount be 90.How can i do this i am just need grand total.this should calculate total 40 and 50 equal 90.

```
                                                 Grand Total = 90
```

Comment: please give more explanations !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(amountColumnName) FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

So you have a table that looks like this:

```
ColA | ColB
20   | 20
10   | 40
```

And you want to output the sum of all those values.

Then I will advise you to sum all the values in the rows and then the values for all those rows this way:

```
select sum(colA + colB) from table
```

Of course, if there are more columns you will have to add them inside the `sum` function.